# Why won't smoke appear?

Tags: smoke-simulation

Been trying to get smoke to appear on my "plane" object, but it won't seem to emit on that or any other object.  What am I missing in my settings? Not sure if there are changes to the newest version of Blender, as most tutorials I've been watching are for older versions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the file that you have more than one smoke emitting objects, there's a separate cylinder under the wheel

Try to

- enable for the domain both "adaptive domain" and "high resolution" (with "show high resolution" to see it in the viewport)

[image]

- set lower density for all the smoke objects, since they are pretty dense (unapplied screw modifier helps in this respect) in the example below I also changed smoke color to see better...

[image]

Since smoke simulation is a difficult topic in itself, I suggest to experiment with a simpler geometry before, and since your scene has complex geometry, you could also "fake" the result emitting smoke from a simpler (but invisible) object, in the end.

Remember, CG you see in the movies is very much about cheating...

Comment: Thanks so much!  It worked.  And that's a great idea about using a simpler object to emit the smoke and then hide it...haven't seen that trick in any tutorials.